# Java : SimpleDateFormat - Unable to parse a string to a date of desired format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I am trying to parse one string to a format `yyyy-MM-dd` and one to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.
I am using `SimpleDateFormat`.

I have used the same method successfully earlier, but now something is going wrong. I get the date in the standard format i.e. `Tue Mar 05 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012` (for `yyyy-MM-dd`) and `Mon Mar 05 13:01:35 GMT+05:30 2012` (for `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) where as I need them to be `2012-03-05` and `2012-03-05 13:01:35` repectively.

This is what I do :

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat tsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
    today = tsdf.parse(tsdf.format(new Date()));
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred"+ e.getMessage());
}

System.out.println(today);
```

**AND**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    // I recieve a string in this format here (refers to 5 march 2012).
    myDate = sdf.parse('2012-03-05');            
    System.out.println(myDate);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Is there a stacktrace? Or what format do you get the date in?

Comment: '2012-03-05' should be "2012-03-05"

Comment: Please show the exception stacktrace(generated by e.printStackTrace())

Comment: Second example is a compile time error - should read `sdf.parse("2012-03-05")`

Comment: @TrueDub: No error. Nothing but a date in the wrong format.

Comment: `''` is a character literal, `""` encloses a string literal

Comment: @radimpe: Yes, but actually I get a string object here, I just wrote the date as an example here.(Thats a typo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
today = tsdf.parse(tsdf.format(new Date()));
System.out.println(today);
```

Looks to me like you expect, that the `Date` instance gets *formatted*. That is not the case. A `Date` instance represents a date that can be *formatted* "to" a string. It is a class that simply holds a `long` value (meaning something like "time in milliseconds").

This would give the expected result:

```
Date today = new Date();
String formattedDate = tsdf.format(today);
System.println(formattedDate);     // <- we print the string!!
```

Comment: You are right, I thought that the date object is formatted. Actually I dont need to print the date, I want to insert a record containing this date in database. I am getting error inserting that.

Comment: What kind of error? Take care to use the correct class: you may want `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not outputting the string that is the result of the formatter, you're outputting the actual date object.  That will always be the result of Date.toString(), which for the JDK you're using is the format you see.  Don't turn the formatted String back into a date object, just print it out!

```
SimpleDateFormat tsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
    String formattedDate = tsdf.format(new Date());
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred"+ e.getMessage());
}

System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

You cannot apply a "format" to a `java.util.Date` object for later use.  It's just a raw number of milliseconds and its toString method will always print the same representation.  You have to convert it into a formatted string and use that string.

Comment: Is there a need to try-catch tsdf.format(new Date())? I understand try-catch is needed for tsdf.parse(String date), but am not convinced we need it for tsdf.format(Date date).

Answer (score 0):

If you want format a `Date` instance, you don't must using `parse` method, you have to use `format` method as following:

```
    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat tsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try
    {
        System.out.println(tsdf.format(today));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error occurred" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

`parse` method use for convert a string to date and `format` method for format a `Date` instance to string by specified format.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using old troublesome date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `LocalDate`

For date-only values, use the `LocalDate` class. Your input value is in standard ISO 8601 format. The ISO 8601 formats are used by default in java.time classes for parsing and generating strings that represent the date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2012-03-05" );
```

To generate such a string, call `toString`.

```
String output = localDate.toString();
```

## `LocalDateTime`

For a string such as `2012-03-05 12:34:56` we have a problem. No offset-from-UTC or time zone is indicated. So it does not represent an actual moment on the timeline, but rather a rough idea about possible moments. This non-moment is represented in java.time by the `LocalDateTime` class.

Your string’s format is a variation on ISO 8601 while the canonical version has a `T` in the middle rather than a space. So one option is to replace the SPACE with a `T`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2012-03-05 12:34:56".replace( " " , "T" );
```

Or define a pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2012-03-05 12:34:56" , formatter );
```

Avoid using such date-time formats lacking in offset or time zone info if indeed they are meant to represent actual moments on the timeline.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To give that value meaning, to determine an actual moment on the timeline, we need to assign the time zone for which the date-time is intended.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId );
```

Calling `toString` generates a String in a format that extends the ISO 8601 standard format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString(); // Yields: 2012-03-05T12:34:56-04:00[America/Montreal]
```

If you want to omit the `T` you could replace with a SPACE using `String::replace` method. Or use a formatter. If you *really* want a string as seen in the Question lacking any offset or time zone info (against my recommendation) use the same formatter shown above.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" );  // Not recommended as it lacks offset/zone info.
String output = zdt.format( formatter );  // Yields: 2012-03-05 12:34:56
```